# Setting up Vagrant for django tutorial

Tags: django, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-16.04

I have found a [django beginner+ tutorial](http://www.gettingstartedwithdjango.com/). However, I encountered an issue I can't resolve by myself.
First I changed all `precise64` to `precise32`, because even if I run 64 bit Xubuntu 16.04, my potato processor does not support VT-X technology, and had to download 32 bit version of Vagrant.
Then, I run `vagrant up` and got error:

```
mixlib-shellout requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Even if my Ruby is 2.3.1p112. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661711/trouble-setting-up-vagrant) similar to my problem. However, when I added lines posted by user Queenvictoria, I got this error message (I paste most of it, but I think bottom part is most important):

```
    ==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: The following extra packages will be installed:
==> default:   dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 libalgorithm-diff-perl
==> default:   libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl libruby1.9.1
==> default:   libstdc++6-4.6-dev libyaml-0-2 make patch ruby1.9.1
==> default: Suggested packages:
==> default:   debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-4.6-multilib gcc-4.6-doc libstdc++6-4.6-dbg
==> default:   libstdc++6-4.6-doc make-doc diffutils-doc ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1
==> default:   graphviz
==> default: The following NEW packages will be installed:
==> default:   build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 libalgorithm-diff-perl
==> default:   libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl libruby1.9.1
==> default:   libstdc++6-4.6-dev libyaml-0-2 make patch ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev
==> default: 0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
==> default: Need to get 14.9 MB of archives.
==> default: After this operation, 44.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
==> default: Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libyaml-0-2 i386 0.1.4-2 [56.9 kB]
==> default: Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libstdc++6-4.6-dev i386 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 [1,643 kB]
==> default: Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++-4.6 i386 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 [6,745 kB]
==> default: Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++ i386 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 [1,444 B]
==> default: Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main make i386 3.81-8.1ubuntu1 [116 kB]
==> default: Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libdpkg-perl all 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 [181 kB]
==> default: Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main patch i386 2.6.1-3 [86.0 kB]
==> default: Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main dpkg-dev all 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 [468 kB]
==> default: Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main build-essential i386 11.5ubuntu2.1 [5,796 B]
==> default: Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main fakeroot i386 1.18.2-1 [87.9 kB]
==> default: Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.19.02-2 [50.7 kB]
==> default: Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl i386 0.04-2build2 [12.9 kB]
==> default: Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-2 [12.7 kB]
==> default: Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libruby1.9.1 i386 1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2
==> default:   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
==> default: Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main ruby1.9.1 i386 1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2
==> default:   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
==> default: Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main ruby1.9.1-dev i386 1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2
==> default:   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
==> default: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby1.9.1/libruby1.9.1_1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
==> default: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby1.9.1/ruby1.9.1_1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
==> default: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby1.9.1/ruby1.9.1-dev_1.9.3.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
==> default: Fetched 9,467 kB in 4s (1,895 kB/s)
==> default: E
==> default: : 
==> default: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Versions of my software:
Virtual Box: 5.0.24
Vagrant 1.8.7
This is the first time when I am using Vagrant. Every time I am trying to `vagrant up`, I am deleting all files, by "remove" option in Virtual Box.
Side question: Is there any beginner (skill level described on GSwD tutorial page) to intermediate django guide? This one looks ok, but amount of troubles I've met while setting up environment is a bit demotivating.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) and a [virtualenv](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/).

Making use of vagrant for a tutorial django setup makes no sense IMO, because you need to solve more issues related to this setup than you benefit from the encapsulated environment. And you can achieve that much easier with the virtualenv.

Except of python packages (which go into the venv) there are no dependencies to other things (sqlite will be your database in that case).

Comment: I know the official tutorial, I was looking for something more advanced.

Comment: sry - got the point. nevertheless i would advise to skip the vagrant part. our trainees after going through the official tutorial usually start with their first personal project - this works quite good - maybe it is an option for you, too?

Comment: Or try the djangogirls one. But definitely don't bother with Vagrant at this point.

Comment: Finished this one as well.

Comment: have you considered writing your own app/project now - just to continue learning? e.g. a calendar app, or a blog app, or a twitter clone, or whatever interests you.